# Swift 4 - Xml Parsing with UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, xml-parsing

I want to take values from XML URL but I don't have any error. I am trying to understand my mistake. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,XMLParserDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var tblView: UITableView!

    var parser = XMLParser()
    var haberler = NSMutableArray()
    var elements = NSMutableDictionary()
    var element = NSString()
    var title1 = NSMutableString()
    var link = NSMutableString()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        parsinDataFromURL()

    }
```

**My function for parsing xml**

```
    func parsinDataFromURL() {
        haberler = []

        parser = XMLParser(contentsOf: NSURL(string: "http://www.haberturk.com/rss/kategori/gundem.xml")! as URL)!

        parser.delegate = self
        parser.parse()
        tblView.reloadData()
    }
```

**didStartElement,FoundCharacters and didEndElement functions**

```
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {
        if (elementName as NSString) .isEqual(to: "item") {

            elements = NSMutableDictionary()
            elements = [:]
            title1 = NSMutableString()
            title1 = " "
            link = " "
        }
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        if element .isEqual(to: "title") {
            title1.append(string)
        }
        else if element.isEqual(to: "link") {
            link.append(string)
        }
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
        if (elementName as NSString) . isEqual(to: "item") {
            if !title1.isEqual(nil) {
                elements.setObject(title1, forKey: "title" as NSCopying)
            }

            if !link .isEqual(nil) {
                elements.setObject(link, forKey: "link" as NSCopying)
            }

            haberler.addObjects(from: [elements])
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return haberler.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ("myCell"))! as UITableViewCell

        if (cell.isEqual(NSNull.self)) {
            cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("myCell", owner: self, options: nil)![0] as! UITableViewCell    
        }

        cell.textLabel?.text = (haberler.object(at: indexPath.row) as AnyObject).value(forKey: "title") as? String

        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = (haberler.object(at: indexPath.row) as AnyObject).value(forKey: "title") as? String

        return cell
    }
}
```

When I'm running in simulator, UITableView is empty (empty UITableViewscreen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWX2C.jpg)

Comment: This is Swift. You should use Swift classes. Use a Swift dictionary, not `NSMutableDictionary`. Use a Swift array, not `NSMutableArray`. Use `String`, not `NSMutableString`. Use `URL`, not `NSURL`.

Comment: What debugging have you done? Are any of the XMLParse delegate methods being called? Is your `haberler` array getting populated?

Comment: I just printed the 'haberler' and it is always shows: 
        {
        link = " ";
        title = " ";
    },

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement

```
func parserDidEndDocument(_ parser: XMLParser) {

    tblView.reloadData()
}
```

//

verify that you set table dataSource in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.tblView.dataSource = self
```

Comment: The OP is already calling `reloadData` after `parse`. `parse` is not asynchronous.

Comment: It's possible the table delegate and data source are connected in the storyboard since the table view is an outlet. Until the OP provides more details about the actual problem, this answer is just a collection of guesses.

Comment: @rmaddy this which i currently do Guesses

Comment: i write the function and i write the "self.tableview.datasource = self" code in to viewDidLoad but it is show "ambiguous reference to member 'tableview(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)"

Comment: tableView name must be tblView as your outlet , copy what in answer and make your code more swifty instead of using objective-c bridged APIs

Comment: I fixed that as tblView but still same. My UITablView is empty.

Comment: parser delegate methods called the array populated with values , print them to verify

Comment: i printed 'parser' and 'parser.delegate'. for parser it is show : "<NSXMLParser: 0x6040001060c0>"

and for parser.delegate it is show = "Optional(<XmlVeriC_ekme.ViewController: 0x7ff6a5608d30>)" ... what do they mean?